# Can all computational complexity results be expressed in terms of programming languages?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, programming-languages

Computational complexity results are often explained in intuitive terms as statements about the possible efficiencies of algorithms to solve certain classes of problems.

However, on a more formal level, all (many?) results actually build on the underlying notion of Turing machines, which provides a precise way to define computation.

My question is then: can all computational complexity statements be fully expressed in terms of lines of (pseudo-)code?

If so, would that mean that one should state all results building on a finite set of "elementary operations" that are allowed in the programming language under consideration? What would be the "elementary operations" in such a context?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) may be of interest.

Comment: Are you aware that big O notation is used to describe algorithm complexity?